# Hide error message if cart is empty in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, categories

In WooCommerce, I am using a function that show an error message and prevent to checkout, if product from one specific category is alone in cart items.

But the error message **remain displayed even if cart is empty**.

How can I disable this function if cart is empty?

Here is my code:

```
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {

    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $category = 'clothing';

    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );

    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';

    // check if this category is the only thing in the cart
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {

        // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Hi there! Looks like your cart only contains products from the %1$s category &ndash; you must purchase a product from another category to check out.', $category_name ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );


/**
 * Checks if a cart contains exclusively products in a given category
 * 
 * @param string $category the slug of the product category
 * @return bool - true if the cart only contains the given category
 */
function sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {

    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
        if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid error message showing when cart is empty, you need to add in your first function condition **`! WC()->cart->is_empty()`** this way:

```
// Check if this category is the only thing in the cart (when cart is not empty)
if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { // <= <=
```

So your first function code will be:

```
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {

    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $category = 'clothing';

    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );

    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';

    // Check if this category is the only thing in the cart (when cart is not empty)
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { // <==

        // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Hi there! Looks like your cart only contains products from the %1$s category &ndash; you must purchase a product from another category to check out.', $category_name ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );
```

Comment: Cool, it works, thanks you! I tried `WC()->cart->is_empty()` but by wrong way. May I know why `// check if this category is the only thing in the cart
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {` is not enough?